# How would I go about making a conditional that checks for a wide range of conditions from an input and prints out the most efficient statement?

Tags: java

Say I have to sort fractions of wholes using if/elseif/else type conditionals. I have 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, and a whole. If I have a whole and 1/2, I would want to print "One whole and one half." If I have 3/4ths I would want to print "three 1/4ths". So on and so forth.

What I'm asking is how would I go about *not* saying "I have one whole and four fourths, two halves, three thirds." rather than "I have one whole" etc. etc.

I want to have an efficient sentence that is not redundant, yet I cannot figure out for the life of me the logic behind this, nor even what to try at all.

I'm not asking for code here, I'm just a bit dumb.

Comment: How would you do it without java ?

Comment: Just add all fractions and use the numeric result (reinterpreted) as source for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a logic like this:

1. Count how much of each fraction you have;

   - Example: Input `1/2`  `1/4` `1/4`  `1/3` `1 whole`, so you have 1 half, 2 quarters, 1 third and 1 whole.
2. Start grouping your fractions from the smallest to largest;

   - Example: considering the previous example, your smallest fraction is a quarter, so you can group your 2 quarters to make 1 half. Now you have 2 halves, 1 third and 1 whole. The next fraction should be a third, but in our example there is just one third, leaving no option to group it with, so you can continue to the next fraction. You can group your 2 halves to make 1 whole. So your final count would be 1 third and 2 wholes.
3. Use the count from the previous step to form a sentence, preferentially from largest to smallest.

   - Example: 2 wholes and 1 third.

You probably will want to add a test to the final step:

- if the count for a fraction is 1 use its singular form, else use its plural

  - Example: `1 whole` `2 wholes`

Hope this answer helps you!

Comment: Hmm. Yeah this is helpful. I think I'm getting closer to the right track now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way here would be to define a fraction type, something like:

```java
public final class Fraction {
   private final int numerator;
   private final int denominator;

   // expose with getters as needed
   private final boolean isWhole;
   private final boolean isTopHeavy;

   public Fraction(final int numerator, final int denominator) {
      this.numerator = numerator;
      this.denominator = denominator;
      isWhole = numerator == denominator;
      isTopHeavy = numerator > denominator; 
   }

   // if your fractions are passed to you as Strings you can add a constructor that takes a string

   @override public toString() {
      // code to print appropriate message
      // using "/" and "%" may be helpful when building the string
   }
}
```

All the logic with how to translate the fraction to a string can go in the `toString` method (and helper methods as required)

You also give yourself a logical location to add additional functionality and operations to the `Fraction` if you need to in the future.